# How redirect directly to the final domain URL rather than a chain through variations of `www` and `https`?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, url, php, apache

When I type `example.com` in the URL it first redirects to `http://example.com` then to `https://example.com` and finally to the `https://www.example.com` (the original address).

Why doesn't it straight away redirect `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`? Otherwise the direct traffic of my website has to go through one extra redirection causing slow load time.

Comment: There's nothing actually wrong with the chained redirect you are seeing (providing this is done early in `.htaccess` - this should not cause a "slow load time") - in fact, this _double redirect_ (1st to HTTPS on the same host) is actually a _requirement_ if you plan on implementing HSTS in the future. These should also be 301 redirects, so the browser will _cache_ them. _Aside:_ "it first redirects to `http://example.com`" - that's not a "redirect", it's simply the initial request (but I guess from your later text that you already know that.)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.htaccess` for the redirections. I suppose it is an internal redirection made by WordPress.

You can try this in the `.htaccess`.

Make sure to have `mod_rewrite` activated in your server.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: You need to include the `OR` flag on the first condition, otherwise it's not going to redirect `http://www.example.com` to HTTPS. Also, don't forget to escape literal dots in the regex and the `QSA` flag is not required here.